# if defined(__AIX) not working on AIX 6.1?

Tags: c, aix

I have the following on AIX 6.1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
#if defined(__AIX)
  printf("hello world");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

I have followed the instructions from http://predef.sourceforge.net/preos.html#sec2 but am scratching my head as to why it does not work or print out "hello world" when I run it?

if I do a "uname" on the box I get "AIX"...and "uname -v" returns "6"...

Any ideas what I can put into the code?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Comment: My mistake....it should be ONE underscore not two...so should be "_AIX" not "__AIX"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be 1 underscore not 2 underscores before "AIX"....solved now ;-)